# Command generated through concatenation behaves differently than hard coded command in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am giving a `SCPI` command to a **DC Voltage Generator** to set and measure the voltage like this:

```
   power_manager.write("VOLTage 3,(@1)")     #Set 3 Volts to channel 1
   power_manager.write("OUTPut:STATe ON,(@1)")  #Switch ON channel 1  
   power_manager.ask("MEAS:VOLT? (@1)")    # Measure the voltage on channel 1
```

There are four channels in the instrument so  '`@1`' means the first channel.

In the first instruction I am setting 3 Volts to channel 1.
Instead of hard-coding I want to pass the set voltage to a function, therefore I generated the string through concatenation like below:

```
   set_voltage = 3 #Passed as function argument
   chan_1_command_string = [ '"', 'VOLTage ', str(set_voltage),  ',' , '(@1)','"']
   chan_1_command = ''.join('{0}'.format(w) for w in chan_1_command_string)
   print chan_1_command
```

I can see that `chan_1_command` is being printed like "`VOLTage 3,(@1)`". But when I run this code instead of hard coding the instrument sends a different response and refuses to program the set voltage.

I think this is not an instrument issue but some issue with `Python` so thought to post in this forum. Any inputs or alternatives are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a subtle difference between your approach and the original string.

In your approach, the string is actually encapsulated with single quotes, the end result being you are sending 2 extra `"` to  your hardware.

Instead of a command that starts with `V`, your command string is starting with `"V`:

```
>>> i = [ '"', 'VOLTage ', str(3),  ',' , '(@1)','"']
>>> ''.join(i)
'"VOLTage 3,(@1)"'
^----------------^
```

To get around this problem, you can simplify your code a bit and use the same string template, with place holders for variables, like this:

```
>>> i = "VOLTage {0},(@1)"
>>> i.format(3)
'VOLTage 3,(@1)'
```

Note how there is only one set of quotes encapsulating the entire string.

Comment: Thank you, I understood how the single quotes in .join was spoiling the command...your solution worked nice.

Comment: when I try with a floating point number for example i.format(1.2), the command fails...any clue?

Comment: Are you sure? `>>> i.format(1.2); 'VOLTage 1.2,(@1)'`

Comment: Yes, I was checking the response of the instrument which is different for a fixed integer and a floating point number, so the test was failing...no problem with the script, thank you again